# High number of ldap queries when unfolding some "ou" in phpldapadmin

Tags: openldap, phpldapadmin

I use phpldapadmin (1.2.6.3) with an openldap backend (2.5.13) on debian 12. I sometime browse large parts of the tree, e.g. clicking on the "+" button in the tree to unfold ou=people. I noticed that it is quite slow (>15s) and that it hit the ldap server with a really high number of queries (thousands of queries for thousands of users).

First there is a query on ou=people (normal), but then log is filled with 2 lines per user :

```
2023-10-02T12:43:54.972185+02:00 testhost slapd[3951356]: conn=1111 op=1 SRCH base="ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=fr" scope=1 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=*)"
2023-10-02T12:43:54.972259+02:00 testhost slapd[3951356]: conn=1111 op=1 SRCH attr=dn
2023-10-02T12:43:55.205803+02:00 testhost slapd[3951356]: conn=1111 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 qtime=0.000023 etime=0.234080 nentries=18851 text=

(...)

2023-10-02T12:44:09.703588+02:00 testhost slapd[3951356]: conn=1111 op=18303 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 qtime=0.000022 etime=0.000110 nentries=1 text=
2023-10-02T12:44:09.703946+02:00 testhost slapd[3951356]: conn=1111 op=18304 SRCH base="uid=user1,ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=fr" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=*))"
2023-10-02T12:44:09.703974+02:00 testhost slapd[3951356]: conn=1111 op=18304 SRCH attr=* +
2023-10-02T12:44:09.703995+02:00 testhost slapd[3951356]: conn=1111 op=18304 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 qtime=0.000023 etime=0.000100 nentries=1 text=
2023-10-02T12:44:09.704304+02:00 testhost slapd[3951356]: conn=1111 op=18305 SRCH base="uid=user2,ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=fr" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=*))"
2023-10-02T12:44:09.704332+02:00 testhost slapd[3951356]: conn=1111 op=18305 SRCH attr=* +
2023-10-02T12:44:09.704353+02:00 testhost slapd[3951356]: conn=1111 op=18305 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 qtime=0.000023 etime=0.000097 nentries=1 text=
2023-10-02T12:44:09.704700+02:00 testhost slapd[3951356]: conn=1111 op=18306 SRCH base="uid=user3,ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=fr" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=*))"
2023-10-02T12:44:09.704728+02:00 testhost slapd[3951356]: conn=1111 op=18306 SRCH attr=* +
```

I was expecting that only the first ldap query could be enough for phpldapadmin to load the results. Is there a way to make phpldapadmin expand the tree with less queries ?

I use the search feature a lot to avoid the slowdowns, but it would be nice if there is a way to avoid the problem in the first place.